# near real time emoji extraction from text

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-nifi

i have a stream flow of text that may contain emoji. i need to extract it into array in scale of near real time then store it on elasticsearch. this stream flows in apache nifi with approximate 100 tweets per seconds.

what is the best or better solution/architecture to came on this need? i have couple of idea that listed below.

A) create a web service to extract emoji from input text and then send nifi flows on to it then gather response.

[image: method A]

B) same previous step, plus using apache kafka.

[image: methid B]

C) change architecture to use some feature of Apache Spark or Storm or Flink.

[image: method C]

D) Elasticsearch custom mapping?

Comment: When you say extract what exactly do you mean? Extract just the emojis and store them or store the entire tweet with emojis onto elasticsearch?

Comment: @sramalingam24 , hi, extract emojis and store both of them. the tweet text field and emoji array field.

Comment: Have you looked at logstash? You could probably just do twitter -> kafka -> logstash -> elasticsearch. You can use logstash filter plugins to filter the emojis. See here for some details on architecture https://www.elastic.co/blog/just-enough-kafka-for-the-elastic-stack-part2

Comment: @sramalingam24 ; no, because of some aspects, in my architecture i must use apache nifi. is there any solution in elasticsearch custom mapping to do this?

Comment: 100 msg per second... Nothing to think about. You can choose anything. Just choose the simplest tool for you.

Comment: @daggett ; thanks. but this speed increase at future (maybe x100-1000 from other sources). but now for practice and achieve experience on mentioned tools what is your advise?

Comment: Asking for architecture/tools recommends are considered off topic questions for Stackoverflow. What we recommend isn't necessarily what you should use because that's our opinion, and doesn't always match your expertise